# How to implement google-maps-like zoom-and-pan system in web?

Tags: php, javascript, actionscript-3

I'm writing a ticket-shop-system atm for reserving tickets for various concerts.
What I have is a php-backend and a webpage that shows a .swf with some actionsscript-3 code in it, to draw in flash some sort of map and make available seats clickable for the end-user.
The problem with this solution is, that there are quite large halls and just making the seats smaller isn't the right solution.

My next idea was to make a google-maps-like interface, so that users can pan and zoom and things like that. But I can't find any information about doing something like this, whether it'll be flash or javascript or something else...

I would appreciate any information regarding this topic!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you want something like Google Maps, why don't you just use Google Maps? Or maps from other places. http://mapstraction.com/ has a good Javascript library for that.

Comment: It's not the map, that I want, it's the zoom/pan system
The "map" has to show the seats in a concert-hall, so it's quite useless to use Google Maps or OpenStreetMap with their maps, imo

Comment: You can declare a custom map while still using the google API : http://code.google.com/intl/fr/apis/maps/documentation/overlays.html#CustomMapTiles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google maps allows you to use their system and provide your own custom map too, so you can overlay your seating chart and nothing else.  You can [read the documentation here](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/overlays.html).

Answer (score 1):

There's a sample pan-zoom flex application you might find helpful:

Source Code for [Pan-Zoom Flex Map](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/samples/fig_panzoom/).

Hope that's helpful.

Comment: thx, marked as second solution but I'll try to implement the "google maps with overlay" method first, first of all because of the non-present loading time... :)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Seadragon (http://seadragon.com). Might be an interesting way to expose the functionality.

Comment: Can't see how to make buttons or something like that...
So it's not usable for me in my situation :(

Comment: Seadragon buttons http://expression.microsoft.com/en-us/gg413297.aspx ... if you look at the API you will find other overlays as well